Extracting Text from led panel
I need to extract the kilogram (kg) values displayed in the image below:

I manually cropped the image to isolate the text part and applied several image processing techniques such as grayscale conversion, thresholding, Gaussian blur, and dilation. However, the results were not as clear as I expected, and Tesseract OCR was unable to read them. Here are some of the processed images:



I am currently using EmguCV and Tesseract, and have tried various tesseract models including tessdata_best (English), lets, and letsgodigital. Unfortunately, none of these attempts have been successful.
The specific language or library used is not crucial, as I plan to convert the solution to C#. The final implementation will be for a mobile app using Xamarin.Forms.
Below is a sample method that I used without success:
public static void Apply()
        {
            var folderName = "letsgodigital";
            var dataname = "letsgodigital";

            string tesseractPath = @$"./{folderName}";
            string imagePath = @"img.jpg";

            Mat image = CvInvoke.Imread(imagePath, ImreadModes.Color);


            Mat blurredImg = new Mat();
            CvInvoke.Blur(image, blurredImg, new Size(9, 9), new Point(-1, -1));

            Mat grayImg = new Mat();
            CvInvoke.CvtColor(blurredImg, grayImg, ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);

            Mat binaryImg = new Mat();
            CvInvoke.Threshold(grayImg, binaryImg, 122, 255, ThresholdType.Binary);

            binaryImg.Save("full_pannel_bw.png");

            using (var engine = new TesseractEngine(tesseractPath, dataname, EngineMode.Default))
            {
                engine.DefaultPageSegMode = PageSegMode.SingleLine;

                using (var img = Pix.LoadFromFile("full_pannel_bw.png"))
                {
                    using (var page = engine.Process(img))
                    {
                        string text = page.GetText();
                        Console.WriteLine("tesseract got: \"{0}\"", text.Trim());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

Edit my final process
but tesseract cannot read that. I get empty text. Now I am trying to make this text on the image darker

static void loggg()
        {
            Mat img = CvInvoke.Imread("5.jpg", ImreadModes.Color);

            VectorOfMat channels = new VectorOfMat();
            CvInvoke.Split(img, channels);

            Mat redChannel = new Mat();
            CvInvoke.Subtract(channels[2], channels[1], redChannel);
            CvInvoke.Subtract(redChannel, channels[0], redChannel);

            CvInvoke.Threshold(redChannel, redChannel, 40, 255, ThresholdType.Binary);


            Mat invertedRedChannel = new Mat();
            CvInvoke.BitwiseNot(redChannel, invertedRedChannel);
            Mat morphKernel = CvInvoke.GetStructuringElement(ElementShape.Rectangle, new Size(2, 2), new Point(-1, -1));
            CvInvoke.MorphologyEx(invertedRedChannel, invertedRedChannel, MorphOp.Close, morphKernel, new Point(-1, -1), 1, BorderType.Constant, new MCvScalar(255));

             Mat dilateKernel = CvInvoke.GetStructuringElement(ElementShape.Rectangle, new Size(1, 1), new Point(-1, -1));
            CvInvoke.Dilate(invertedRedChannel, invertedRedChannel, dilateKernel, new Point(-1, -1), 1, BorderType.Constant, new MCvScalar(0));

            invertedRedChannel.Save("darker_red_text.jpg");

            img.Dispose();
            redChannel.Dispose();
            invertedRedChannel.Dispose();
            channels.Dispose();
        }


you REALLY need to adjust the exposure of your camera. the LEDs are saturating the sensor. bad. very very bad. dial the exposure down. nobody cares about all the rest of the picture, only the display.

here's a recipe I prototyped with some ancient graphical "boxes and pipes" thing: adjust gamma, lowpass, (to HSL, select Saturation | select Red channel only), binarize. -- you can substitute and rearrange various parts of that, like type of lowpass, do it before or after channel selection, ... https://i.sstatic.net/65Sdyo1B.jpg I'm not gonna write C#. I can offer Python. there is no guarantee that anything I suggest will work without adjustments on other pictures.

or... just send the picture off to some AI web service and have them pick the digits out of it. AI is good at that.

@ChristophRackwitz thank you for your answer. It looks very clear. I've tried with the Google API, and it works, but I prefer to handle it locally. I would appreciate it if you could share Python code with me; I'll try to convert it to C#. Additionally, my previous approach involved selecting the red channel as well, but the outcome wasn't as clear as yours.

I'll post a proper answer in a few hours, assuming I'll remember ;)

First some comments on the picture:

It's upscaled. The digital resolution is 2496 by 3328 pixels but the optical resolution is something like 3.3x less. Upsampled pixels are clearly identifiable.
It's saturated. Some of the brightest "red" pixels in the LED panel aren't really red but white. The mechanism is complex and there are likely multiple effects at play. Light bleeds into adjacent pixels (other colors), which becomes noticeable when it's a lot of light.

Recommendations:

Don't use "digital zoom". Not this type anyway. It gains you nothing.
Dial the physical exposure down, i.e. shorter exposure time and/or less aperture. A digital filter (gain, adjusting brightness/contrast after the fact) will do nothing. You should care that the LED panel is within the dynamic range, i.e. not saturating the sensor. If you do it right, all the surroundings look dark, including the dark parts of the LED panel.



The displayed text is bright and red. You could exploit both properties. So you would select the red channel of the picture and then threshold.
This is just the red channel:

I'll apply a "gamma" mapping, which is nonlinear. It's something one can try, and keep it if the results turn out better. If it were linear, it wouldn't do much of anything, to a threshold anyway (which comes later).

The panel's dark LEDs still look fairly light (level of ~0.25) but not as bright as before (~0.5). One could apply alternative or additional mappings to get the dark parts of the panel even darker.
This already constitutes a threshold of sorts... with manually picked values.

Now you can also see the LEDs and spaces between them in the letters. I'll just apply a lowpass to smooth that out. That'll help with the thresholding in that there won't be "noise" inside and outside of the letters from those "outliers".

For thresholding, it's usually a good idea to try automatic algorithms like Otsu. While figuring this out, Otsu often gave me thresholds that caused the letters to connect, so I worked with manually chosen thresholds most of the time. With the extra contrast stretching, which literally leaves only black between all the letters (see last pic), Otsu has no choice but to "work". This is again with a manually picked threshold.

I think that looks good enough even for simple old Tesseract OCR. If it needs inverting, just invert it.


Here is some Python, using OpenCV functions that should be equivalent even in third-party C# bindings.
I immediately convert to floating point. This prevents clipping or wraparound of the numbers if I exceed the "usual" value range (i.e. values can go below 0 and over 255/1.0). It's also just convenient for some of the math. imshow() interprets floats as ranging from 0.0 to 1.0 but imwrite() just converts to integer, so there you'd have to scale back.
im = cv.imread("QsvdNqcn.jpg")

# convert to float32 and scale to 0.0 .. 1.0
im = im * np.float32(1/255) # Mat::convertTo() with rtype=CV_32F and alpha=1.0/255.0

# getting a region, just for demonstration purposes
(x,y,w,h) = 763, 1281, 1167, 388
im = im[y:y+h, x:x+w] # Mat::operator()(cv::Rect)

(blue, green, red) = cv.split(im)

red_linear = red ** (1/0.45) # cv::pow()

# more contrast stretching to make "dark" parts darker
vmin, vmax = 0.7, 1.0
red_linear = (red_linear - vmin) / (vmax - vmin) # cv::Mat in C++ supports such expressions too

lowpassed = cv.GaussianBlur(red_linear, None, sigmaX=4.0)

(th, mask) = cv.threshold(lowpassed, 0.25, 1.0, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
# with Otsu, that'd take converting back to uint8 ranged 0..255
# (th, mask) = cv.threshold(np.clip(lowpassed * 255, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8), 128, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY | cv.THRESH_OTSU)


Thank you a lot, I converted this code to c# and it works as expected. The only issue that I have different images of the same LED display panel. And your code does not work  for them because you gave exact coordinates. But I'll try to extract this part only

feel free to post such pictures so I can refine the approach on them. -- the cropping was just for demonstration. you can apply this to the whole image. you will see responses for other bright objects then, not just the red text. another operation or two will identify the location of the red text.

I played around some more with basic techniques to locate the red text. unfortunately, it's very much the same color as some bits of the background (tree branches). you might want to just train AI for locating the LED matrix display. if you have the patience, you can even train it to directly infer the text on the display.

Thank you for your reply.
I uploaded all images that I have
https://ibb.co/C6v6cY0
https://ibb.co/q5T7nLV
https://ibb.co/28QVjDf
https://ibb.co/tDxvSz5
It looks quite challenging.  Tomorrow I'll talk to my boss to use Google Vision API.
But the fact that it will be used with the phone would be an advantage for the user to try to read with the camera at various angles until reading the text.

some of those look like they catch only some of the display's flashing. I think you might have to control the camera's exposure time to be 100% (of a frame) to avoid losing any of the LED flashes. those matrix displays flash each LED in turn, which looks ok to humans and in "longer" exposure picture, but not if the camera tries to deal with daylight conditions.

Thank you for your reply. Today, I tried using Paddle OCR, and it did a very good job with image processing and OCR. However, I think I need to use a web service because the mobile phones may not be able to handle it.
